# requestAnimationFrame running before being called by function

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a simple timer (counting up from 0) with JavaScript and requestAnimationFrame. I want to start the timer from 0 when something is clicked. Currently my code displays the timer when the button is clicked, but it looks to me like requestAnimationFrame is running before the function is even called. If you load the code on a web page and wait a few seconds, then click the button, you will see the timer doesn't begin at 0, it starts at however many seconds it has been since the page first loaded. I'm at a loss and googling has not helped me figure out why/how the timer is starting counting before the function has been called.

My current code:

```html
<div class="time">
  Time: <label id="labelTime"></label>
</div>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<script>
  const button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', clickButton);

  function clickButton() {
    runTimer();
  }

  function runTimer() {
    let rAF_ID;

    let rAFCallback = function(callback) {
      let count = callback;

      let s = Math.floor((count / 1000) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      let m = Math.floor((count / 60000) % 60);

      document.getElementById('labelTime').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
      rAF_ID = requestAnimationFrame(rAFCallback);
    }
    rAF_ID = requestAnimationFrame(rAFCallback);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The parameter to your animation function should be named `timestamp` (or similar) and not `callback` because it isn't a `function` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp` (`DOMHighResTimeStamp`) value passed into your `rAFCallback` function does not start from when the animation was first run, instead it has a "time origin" which varies on the context.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp

> - If the script's global object is a `Window`, the time origin is determined as follows:
>
>   - If the current `Document` is the first one loaded in the `Window`, the time origin is the time at which the browser context was created.
>   - If during the process of unloading the previous document which was loaded in the window, a confirmation dialog was displayed to let the user confirm whether or not to leave the previous page, the time origin is the time at which the user confirmed that navigating to the new page was acceptable.
>   - If neither of the above determines the time origin, then the time origin is the time at which the navigation responsible for creating the window's current Document took place.
> - If the script's global object is a WorkerGlobalScope (that is, the script is running as a web worker), the time origin is the moment at which the worker was created.
> - In all other cases, the time origin is undefined.

So if you want to get a delta-time value from when the animation was started, you'll need to do that yourself, like so:

```
let timestampAtStart = null;
let lastRequestId    = null;

function myAnimateFunction( timestamp ) {
    if( !timestampAtStart ) {
        timestampAtStart = timestamp;
    }

    let timeSinceStart = timestamp - timestampAtStart;

    console.log( timeSinceStart );

    lastRequestId = window.requestAnimationFrame( myAnimateFunction );
}

function startAnimation() {

    if( lastRequestId ) window.cancelAnimationFrame( lastRequestId );

    timestampAtStart = null;

    lastRequestId = window.requestAnimationFrame( myAnimateFunction );
}
```